# Should this oxymoron question be reopened?

Tags: discussion, closed-questions, specific-question

[Oxymoron pronunciation](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/584474/oxymoron-pronunciation)

This question is closed for not including research. Is this because the specific dictionaries are not cited?

I think the question is fine, if that is the only problem.

I think it should be reopened.

Comment: ? You're still a mod, you could have opened it single handedly.   In a similar vein, why are so many on-topic questions, from 10 years ago to this recent one, being voted to be closed nowadays?

Comment: @Mari-LouA it is frowned upon for a mod to override a community closed question.

Comment: Three votes in favour of closing barely constitutes "community" driven; however, a mod is elected by the community. They are trusted to do the right thing (most of the time!) 

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I agree and the question is now opened.

It's easy to say that different people pronounce a word differently, but it's not always easy to explain who or especially why. But the [top answer](https://english.stackexchange.com/a/584603/191178) does that and the process to get there certainly wasn't as trivial as looking it up.